# Gradual typing in Dhall

Tags: rowtype, dhall, gradual-typing

The Dhall website has a nice example:

```
{- You can optionally add types

   `x : T` means that `x` has type `T`
-}

let Config : Type =
      {- What happens if you add another field here? -}
      { home : Text
      , privateKey : Text
      , publicKey : Text
      }

let makeUser : Text -> Config = \(user : Text) ->
      let home       : Text   = "/home/${user}"
      let privateKey : Text   = "${home}/.ssh/id_ed25519"
      let publicKey  : Text   = "${privateKey}.pub"
      let config     : Config = { home, privateKey, publicKey }
      in  config

let configs : List Config =
      [ makeUser "bill"
      , makeUser "jane"
      ]

in  configs
```

Like the comment asks me to do, I add another field: `foo : Text` to the type `Config` and now the example fails to typecheck.
This leaves me without a way to gradually add types to existing projects. I'm missing an escape hatch to allow me to gradually add knowledge as I become more familiar with the dynamic configuration of a project that I don't own.

I bet this is a common situation: "I'm maintaining a project I don't own, configured in YAML or JSON without a schema, or with a loosely defined schema."

I believe what I want is called "row-polymorphism" which [seems to have already been discussed](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/pull/494) (and rejected?) in the Dhall issues, but what alternative do I have to solve the same issue? From my perspective, it seems like I cannot use Dhall in the case where I don't have total information?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the most ergonomic solution would be language support for row polymorphism.  See, for example, another proof-of-concept project of mine which does support row polymorphism:

- [Fall-from-grace](https://github.com/Gabriel439/grace)

However, Dhall does have a language feature which can still help here, which is support for projecting a record's fields by the expected type.  In other words, given a record `r` containing a superset of the fields in `Config`, you can project out just the fields of interest using `r.(Config)`.

Normally I'd illustrate how this would work in the context of the example you referenced from dhall-lang.org, but the issue for that specific example is that there's no way it can silently ignore the presence of the extra `foo` field, even if Dhall were to support row polymorphism.  This is because the `makeUser` function *produces* a `Config` instead of consuming a `Config`, so if you commit to producing that extra field then you have to actually add the expected field.

However, in the spirit of your request I'll use a related example which I believe is closer to what you had in mind.  The only difference is that we'll change our function to one that *consumes* a `Config`:

```
let Config : Type = { home : Text, privateKey : Text, publicKey : Text }

let render =
      λ(config : Config) →
        ''
        Home: ${config.home}
        Private Key: ${config.privateKey}
        Public Key: ${config.publicKey}
        ''

let example =
      { home = "/home/gabriella"
      , privateKey = "/home/gabriella/.ssh/id_ed25519"
      , publicKey = "/home/gabriella/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub"
      }

in  render example
```

We'd like to be able to add another `foo` field to example but without breaking the `render` function.  In other words, we want the `render` function to silently ignore any fields other than the ones in the `Config` type.

Normally, in a language with row polymorphism you'd address this by changing the type of `render` to something like this:

```
let render =
      λ(config : { home : Text, privateKey : Text, privateKey : Text | r }) →
        ''
        Home: ${config.home}
        Private Key: ${config.privateKey}
        Public Key: ${config.publicKey}
        ''

let example =
      { home = "/home/gabriella"
      , privateKey = "/home/gabriella/.ssh/id_ed25519"
      , publicKey = "/home/gabriella/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub"
      , foo = "bar"
      }

in  render example
```

… where the `r` in the type of `render` denotes "other fields that we want to ignore".  Dhall doesn't support that, as you noted, but if we use Dhall's support for projecting fields by type, we can do this:

```
let Config : Type = { home : Text, privateKey : Text, publicKey : Text }

let render =
      λ(config : Config) →
        ''
        Home: ${config.home}
        Private Key: ${config.privateKey}
        Public Key: ${config.publicKey}
        ''

let example =
      { home = "/home/gabriella"
      , privateKey = "/home/gabriella/.ssh/id_ed25519"
      , publicKey = "/home/gabriella/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub"
      , foo = "bar"
      }

in  render example.(Config)
```

It is not as ergonomic as row-polymorphism, but at least it addresses the use case of making the code insensitive to changes in the upstream input that add new fields.

Comment: Thanks for your very elaborate answer. I have a follow up question:

Since what I need is to keep the fields that I don't know about, is there a way to say "I need _at least_ these fields", such that when I inevitably convert to yaml or json, the unspecified fields are not lost? 

If I understand projections correctly, you are discarding the unknown fields, which is not what I need.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this answer is the escape hatch I'm needing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142767/how-to-merge-a-dynamically-named-record-with-a-static-one-in-dhall